# Searching for Clive Granger's 1972 paper on time series decomposition from the Budapest Conference

Tags: time-series, arima, references, autoregressive, box-jenkins

In 1972 Clive Granger presented a seminal work on the Box-Jenkins Time Series methods as a conference paper:

C. W. J. GRANGER, Time Series Modelling and Interpretation, Paper presented to the European Econometric Congress, Budapest, 1972.

However I am unable to find this paper in any library or archive or through numerous searches.  Does anyone know where it can be obtained?

Comment: I don't know but Granger and Timo Terisvirta were collaborators so Timo may know ? It's worth an email to him.

Comment: Granger & Morris (1976) had the same title, so perhaps it was an updated version. https://doi.org/10.2307/2345178

Comment: I have the Granger and Morris reference - but various references to the earlier conference paper suggest there was a lot more content...